# Dynamically loading a class in Java

Tags: java, dynamic

I looked up the syntax and searched the api but am still confused about the process. I also searched Stackoverflow.  What is the proper way to load a class and create an object out of it dynamically?  In otherwords I want the user to specify what type of object they want to create, and then create that type of object.  I don't want a menu, because I want them to be able to choose any class within the current directory.

Comment: Are you trying to load a class from the binary.class file or by class name?

Comment: @JustinWaugh Hi Justin, is the accepted answer suitable to load a .class file?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Assuming the class has no-arg constructor, the simplest way would be -

```
Object newObject = Class.forName(strFullyQualifiedClassName).newInstance();
```

Reference - [java.lang.Class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29)

Comment: what if it has arg, and how do I call a method on the class -- how do I cast newObject just by the name of the class? When I try calling a method of the class on type Object it tells me the method is undefined for object.

Comment: If you do not know the type of the class at compile time you will have to use reflection to find and call methods.  If the constructor has an argument you use `getDeclaredConstructor()` on the class returned from `Class.forName` as shown by the answer from Mike Samuel

Comment: +1 to Justin. Also, practically speaking, it cannot be that you know absolutely nothing about the class as then it will be very difficult to actually use it. Having these unknown classes implement a particular interface is usually a good strategy. you can then reference these objects by the interfaces so that you can call methods on them, etc.

Comment: what is the the fully qualified class name of a class?

Comment: You shouldn't use `.newInstance()`.  If the zero argument constructor throws checked exceptions, `.newInstance()` will launder those as runtime exceptions, so you will lose exception safety.  From the javadoc : "Use of this method effectively bypasses the compile-time exception checking that would otherwise be performed by the compiler."

Comment: @MikeSamuel do you have a suggestion for what to do instead?

Comment: I get "java.lang.InstantiationException" error, whatever class name I use! E.g. ""java.io.File", "java.util.Locale", "java.util.zip.ZipFile" ...

Answer (score 7):

[`ClassLoader.loadClass`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass%28java.lang.String%29) will load a class.  You get a classloader by `myClass.getClassLoader()` and you should fall back to `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()` if that is null.

Once you've got a class instance, you can get its constructors via [`getDeclaredConstructor(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29).
So if you have a `public class MyClass` with a constructor like `public MyClass(String) { ... }` then

```
Class<MyClass> clazz = MyClass.class;
Constructor<MyClass> ctor = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class);
MyClass instance = ctor.newInstance("foo");
```

The above ignores a bunch of possible exceptions.

Comment: is MyClass an instance or a static reference to the class? Is there any way I can get the contructor of a class by passing its name as a string to a method? Or any way similiar to that?

Comment: `MyClass` is the name of the class in this example.  A class can have multiple constructors (or none for interfaces); there is no "the constructor" for a class.

Comment: The `MyClass.class` may be confusing syntax.  It is just a way of referring to the class instance for `MyClass`.  So `String.class.isInstance(x)` is another way of saying `x instanceof String`.

Comment: how do I create an instance without actually hardcoding the class name?  I want to load the class by passing a string to a function and it contructs and instantiates a object of that class.

Comment: @rubixibuc, `Class<?> clazz = myClassLoader.loadClass(className)` as described in the first paragraph.

Comment: @MikeSamuel : what if I need to instanciate a class wich is load dynamically, but eclipse doesn't recognize the name of the class ? I've detailed my question here : can you check it please ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16104605/dynamically-loading-jar-to-create-a-webservice-client Thank you :)

Comment: Can you please give an example of `public MyClass(String) { ... }`? I don't know what the brackets should contain ... Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I got working. This is not a finihsed product, but is just test to see if I could get it to work. Thank you to everyone that answered the questoin :-).

```
public class SimLoader {  
  public static void main(String[] args)  
  {  
    try {  
      Object simulator = Class.forName("SimX").newInstance();  
      ((SimInterface)simulator).run();  
    }  
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {}  
    catch(InstantiationException e) {}  
    catch(IllegalAccessException e) {}  
  }  
}

interface SimInterface {  
 void run();  
} 

class SimX implements SimInterface  
{  
  public void run() {  
    System.out.println("Success");  
  }  
}
```

Comment: Best solution for me. But not forget to use FullyQualifiedName for Class (like com.mycomapy.SimX, in your example maybe not needed).

Comment: Where does  (SimInterface) come from? Java 11 compiler cannot find that simbol. How can this be used?