# Creating an object by String in java

Tags: java, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamically loading a class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571466/dynamically-loading-a-class-in-java)

hi
i am trying to create a method that gets a String argument, and returns a new Object of the same name. i.e. if the argument is "Mod", the method will return new Mod();

is there a way to do it without a lot of if statements? 
thanks!

Comment: java.lang.Class.forName(className)

Comment: I believe this to be a duplicate of [Dynamically loading a class in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571466/dynamically-loading-a-class-in-java).

Comment: While loading classes using reflection has some occasional good uses, it usually means a flawed design.  What are you actually trying to achieve by doing it?  You have stated a strategy, but no goal, which is often more important.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With reflection:

```
/**
 * @param type A fully qualified Java type
 */
public Object create(String type) throws Exception {
  return Class.forName(type).newInstance();
}
```

Read the corresponding Javadocs to understand what's going on