# Dynamically loading Jar and instanciate an Object of a loaded Class

Tags: java, web-services, dynamic, client, classloader

I try to load dynamically a jar into my Java project.

Here's the class loader's code :

```
public class ClassLoad {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String filePath = new String("C:/Users/Mehdi/Desktop/JavaClassLoader/jarred.jar");

    URL myJarFile = null;
    try {
        myJarFile = new URL("file://"+filePath);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        System.out.println("1");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[]{myJarFile});

    Class Jarred = null;
    try {
        Jarred = cl.loadClass("com.jarred.exp.Jarred");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("2");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Method simpleWrite = null;
    try {
        simpleWrite = Jarred.getMethod("simpleWrite", new Class[] {String.class});
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        System.out.println("3");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        System.out.println("4");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Object JarredObj = null;
    try {
        JarredObj = Jarred.newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        System.out.println("5");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        System.out.println("6");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        Object response = simpleWrite.invoke(JarredObj, "\nHello Mehdi ! It works hamdoulillah :D");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

and the Class which is included into the Jar :

```
package com.jarred.exp;

public class Jarred {

public void simpleWrite(String str) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

}

It gives me :

```
2
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jarred.exp.Jarred
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at ClassLoad.main(ClassLoad.java:25)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at ClassLoad.main(ClassLoad.java:32)
```

Do you have any idea about this ? Thank you.

Comment: proxy it through an interface

Comment: thank you. I know. The problem is about recognizing the interface or the class or anything in the loaded jar.

Comment: Nope, define an interface for the Service class in your project and use that. Add a factory method that loads the jar and return an instance of the class, classname should be a String parameter of the factory method. Or since you know the name of the class, you can obtain directly an instance via Class.forName(String) method

Comment: Thank you. But the interface is already defined in the jar and it's exactly : `McintWebserviceSEI `. Or I didn't understand what you said*

Comment: You need some sort of glue between your application and the webservice lib, adding an interface is IMHO the most clean way. You may invoke something completely dinamically but that would be a really big effort.

Comment: Thank you @BigMike do you have any link where I could begin ?

Comment: Why are you adding a URL to the system classloader instead of creating your own URLClassLoader that uses the system one as a parent?  Java VMs are not even required to have a system classloader, so this is extremely brittle code.

Comment: @MikeSamuel : can you check my code ? I've updated it

Comment: @Mehdi, your class loader creation looks better now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your file URL is invalid.

["File URIs in Windows"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows.aspx) says

> For the local Windows file path
>
> `C:\Documents and Settings\davris\FileSchemeURIs.doc`
>
> The corresponding valid file URI in Windows is:
>
> `file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/davris/FileSchemeURIs.doc`

which shows that *three slashes* are needed after the colon, but the URL you are computing in

```
String filePath = new String("C:/Users/Mehdi/Desktop/JavaClassLoader/jarred.jar");

URL myJarFile = null;
try {
    myJarFile = new URL("file://"+filePath);
```

has only *two slashes* after the `file:`.  Perhaps

```
    myJarFile = new URL("file://"+filePath);
```

should be

```
    myJarFile = new URL("file:///"+filePath);
```

or alternatively you could use [`java.io.File.toURI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toURI%28%29) thus

```
File myJarFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Mehdi\\Desktop\\JavaClassLoader\\jarred.jar");
if (!myJarFile.isFile()) {
  throw new FileNotFoundException("Missing required JAR: " + myJarFile.toString());
}
URL myJarUrl = myJarFile.toURI().toURL();
```

with appropriate exception handling.

Comment: Excuse me, but do you have any idea if I want to load dyanmically the param Types of the method which I'm not supposed to know them using `getParameterTypes()` I guess. Thank you :)

Comment: @Mehdi, `Class.getDeclaredMethods` will let you loop over the methods and pick one that looks appropriate.  Just be sure to check the modifiers to make sure it's public.

Comment: @Mehdi, I'm not understanding your problem.  If you know how to load a class dynamically, then don't you know how to load the param classes dynamically?

Comment: Thank you. But what I want to do is replace the following line : `simpleWrite = Jarred.getMethod("simpleWrite", new Class[] {String.class});` 
with something like : 
`simpleWrite = Jarred.getMethod("simpleWrite", new Class[] {PARAMS TYPES LOADED DYNAMICALLY})`;

Comment: sorry, I meant method's signature

Comment: @Mehdi, and my question is why can't you do that?  Are you having trouble creating the parameter types array?

Comment: Exactly. I don't have any idea about how can I do it when I get the method with `getMethod`. Thank you.

Comment: I get the type parameters but in an array, and I need to loop on it.
Do you have any idea ?

Comment: @Mehdi, ask another question.  This can't be done effectively in comments because I can't get a good idea of what you've done in a few hundred characters.

Comment: thank you :) here's the link of the question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222297/display-all-array-elements-of-a-method-param-types