# display all array elements of a method param types

Tags: java, dynamic, reflection

I want to get all the element of the array which contains the Param types of a method (getted dynamically with **Java.reflect**),

here's the code if I have 2 params in the method :

```
Method testMethod = c.getMethod(method.getName(), new Class[] {int.class, String.class});
```

But it should be dynamic, so I use : `method.getTypeParameters()` which returns an array on all the param types.

Then when I write :

```
Method testMethod = c.getMethod(method.getName(), new Class[] {method.getParameterTypes});
```

but it gives me that : ***Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class[] to Class***

the I understood that I have to loop on parameters because I have :

```
method.getParameterTypes[0] // gives  "int"
```

and

```
method.getParameterTypes[1] // gives  "String"
```

So how can I achieve this ? a loop maybe ? do you have any idea about this ? Thank you.

Comment: Are you using `getParameterTypes()` or `getTypeParameters()` (you have both in the example)? There's a big difference...

Comment: I use `getParameterTypes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Method testMethod = c.getMethod(
>     method.getName(), new Class[] {method.getParameterTypes});
> ```

should be

```
Method testMethod = c.getMethod(
    method.getName(), method.getParameterTypes());
```

The first problem is that you're missing the `()` at the end of `getParameterTypes`.  Java requires explicit parentheses when calling a method.

The second problem is that you're trying to put the result of `getParameterTypes`, a `Class<?>[]` inside a `Class[]`.  The only thing a `Class[]` can contain is individual classes, not arrays, so just use the array returned by `getParameterTypes()`.

---

I'm unclear why you're doing this at all though.  You can take a `Method` from an interface and apply it to an instance of that interface just fine without looking up the method on the instance's concrete class.  Similarly for abstract classes.  You shouldn't need to use one methods signature to get another method unless there's a hole in your inheritance graph or some kind of strange corresponding static method convention.  Either of those is probably an opportunity for refactoring.

The less reflection in your code-base, the easier it will be for people to learn, and the more mileage you will get out of bug finders and other analysis tools, and the fewer incomplete class-path problems you will have.

Comment: Thank you it works. The process is that an extern application sends me the method name it's parameters and an ID, and  I need to load from a directory a jar which has this ID. The jar contains the proxy classes of the webservice client, to finally consume a webservice and execute the method with it's pamaters. I know that's confusing..

Answer (score 0):

Use `Arrays.toString(method.getParameterTypeas())` if you want to *see* the types. Use loop if you want to iterate over them and use them:

```
for (Class<?> type : method.getParameterTypeas()) {
    // use the type
}
```