# How to load .class and call one of its methods

Tags: java, reflection, urlclassloader

I've compiled at runtime a java file on file system which is a very simple class:

```
public class Test {

public static int res(int a, int b) {   
    return a*b;
}
```

}

now I just want to call res method from my project (that will be a jar), but my code produce `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Test`

and this is how I've loaded the class:

```
URL[] urls = new URL[] {new URL("file:///"+UtilOverriding.getFile1().replace("java", "class"))};
        URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
        Class clazz = loader.loadClass("Test");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016092/how-to-load-classes-at-runtime-from-a-folder-or-jar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16104605/dynamically-loading-jar-and-instanciate-an-object-of-a-loaded-class

Comment: You seem to replace .java extension with .class extension.Seriously,this is not java compilation.A java class is in byte code compiled by a java compiler

Comment: @KumarAbhinav I know thanks, infact that you are mentioning is a class loading not a java file compiling (operaration that I did before that piece of code)

Comment: I need to load a .class not a .class in a .jar

Answer (score 1):

When you specify a class path you have to provide the *directory* which is the parent to all your packages.  Try instead.

```
 new URL("file:///"+UtilOverriding.getFile1().getParent()}
```