# Java Support for Different Operating Systems

Tags: windows, macos, operating-system

I am just getting into creating apps and I was wondering how you are supposed to handle running on different operating systems. My goal is to be able to set the dockImage on Mac and the taskBarImage on Windows within the same program. I don't know if this is possible or not. I have the  com.apple.eawt.Application package imported to set the dockImage on Mac OS but when I tried running it on a Windows, it wouldn't let me run the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to dynamically load these classes at runtime, with a try/catch block to handle attempting to run or load code for the wrong platform.

You may also need to abstract out both implementations with an interface declaration (defined by the app, but implemented by the dynamically loaded classes) such that the application isn't attempting to compile in OS-specific code. You want your application code to not be importing or referencing any com.apple.* classes or interfaces.

Some references:

[Dynamically loading a class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571466/dynamically-loading-a-class-in-java)

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html