# Get a class dynamically

Tags: java, android

I have a class DataGridView this is the constructor

```
//this class is created in the MainActivity 
public DataGridView(Context CTX,TableLayout Tl,int[] Weight) {
    this.CTX = CTX;
    this.Tl = Tl; 
    this.Weight= Weight;
}
```

I want to add a parameter that receive a class(what ever class) for example MainActivity

```
public DataGridView(Context CTX,TableLayout Tl,int[] Weight,Class MA) {
    this.CTX = CTX;
    this.Tl = Tl; 
    this.Weight= Weight;
    //HERE
    this.MA = MA;
}
```

To do this in The MainActivity

```
public void Create(){
    int[] weight = new int[2];
    weight[0] = 1;
    weight[1] = 3;
    Dr= new DataGridView(CTX,Dt,weight,this);
    String[] Columnas = new String[2];
    Columnas[0] = "ID";
    Columnas[1] = "MATERIA";
    Dr.ColumnsAdd(Columnas);
}
```

I dont want to put in the parameter MainActivity MA, Because i will send another Activities to this object. I Want to get it Dinamically.

Comment: And what to you want with this dynamic class ?

Comment: Please note that in Java we don't start variable and method names with a capital letter.

Comment: Perhaps you want to call the constructor with this.getClass()?  Also you might want to parametrize the Class type, like Class<? extends Activity>, or whatever the "highest" class you can work with is.  Also please see the previous comments by @pdegand59 and maksimov.  Please, please, please do what maksimov is recommending.

Comment: Why won't you just have the Parameter signature as "Activity ma" and pass which ever Activity you wish?

Comment: Thanks maksimov, I'm a little bit new in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a > [link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html)
explaining how to load or reload a class dynamically in Java using reflection. Also, you might find this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571466/dynamically-loading-a-class-in-java) useful, and apply it like this:

this.MA = Class.forName(MA.class.getName()).newInstance();

Also, you should pay attention, if you want to use what it previously contained, you have to follow the indications in the first link to reload that class.