# How to use ClassLoader or Class to programatically load a Class

Tags: java, class, reflection, classloader, dynamic-class-loaders

I have two classes

```
package pack2;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
class eg
{
    public void show()
    {
        System.out.println("ClassPath set to this class");
    }
}
```

this is in C:\NNK\pack2. the fully qualified name is pack2.eg

another program is

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.net.*;
class classload
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        //have to load the eg class here. Dont know what i have done below is right or wrong
        try 
        {
            Class b=Class.forName("pack2.eg");
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try
        {
            eg z=(eg) b.newInstance();
        }
        catch(InstantiationException l)
        {
            l.printStackTrace();
        }
        z.show();
        System.out.println("b.getName()="+b.getName());
    }
}
```

this program is at C:\NNK
I have to load the eg program here. I tried to learn it in Oracle saw other related stack overflow questions of it. 
[Dynamically loading a class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571466/dynamically-loading-a-class-in-java)
But it didn't work i keep getting the error b is Unknown and z is unknown symbol.
Also is there a way to use the directory filename(eg: C:\NNK\pack2\eg) to load a class

Comment: Read up on Java scope rules.  You must declare `b` and `z` at the top level before the first `try`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to multiple errors already identified by Jim Garrison answer, you've declared your class with "default" scope. This means it can only be referenced via classes in the same package.

should be

```
public class eg   // <== public
{
    public void show()
    {
        System.out.println("ClassPath set to this class");
    }
}
```

And no need for separate try catches, why not just throw from the main method... If any step failed, e.g. defining b, you couldn't do anything more anyway...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Class b = Class.forName("pack2.eg");
    eg z = (eg)b.newInstance();
    z.show();

    System.out.println("b.getName()=" + b.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a scope issue. Move the declarations of `b` and `z` outside the first `try`, as in:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    //have to load the eg class here. Dont know what i have done below is right or wrong
    Class b;
    eg z;
    try 
    {
        b=Class.forName("pack2.eg");
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try
    {
        z=(eg) b.newInstance();
    }
    catch(InstantiationException l)
    {
        l.printStackTrace();
    }
    z.show();
    System.out.println("b.getName()="+b.getName());
}
```

You will probably have to make `pack2.eg` `public` as well

Comment: is there a way of doind this without knowing the loaded class name. i have created `eg z`, but what if i dont know the class name. can i use Object and do it? If yes then what's the way

Comment: the error is thrown as unknown symobol eg. o I changed it.
`Object b;

try {

b=Class.forName("pack2.eg").newInstance();

}

catch(ClassNotFoundException e){

e.printStackTrace();

}

b.show();`
Still error is thrown as cannot find symbol b.